# Can C++ functions return a pointer to an array of known length?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I have a class that contains a `static constexpr` array of `const char`s, which i would like to make available via a `c_str()` method:

```
class my_class {
  private:
    static constexpr const char c_str_[6] = {'c', 'h', 'a', 'r', 's', '\0'};
  public:
    static constexpr const char* c_str() {
      return c_str_;
    }
};
```

This works, but has an unfortunate effect:
It removes the length of the pointed-to array from the type:

```
decltype(my_class::c_str()) // equivalent to const char*
```

What I'd really like is some way to achieve this:

```
decltype(my_class::c_str()) // equivalent to const char[6]
```

I understand that in either case the returned object will be a pointer; I would just like to preserve the length of the pointed-to array in the type.  Kind of like how `decltype("string literal")` is `const char[15]`, not `const char*`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean like returning a reference to `c_str_`?

```
static constexpr decltype(c_str_)& c_str() { return c_str_; }
```

or

```
static constexpr auto& c_str() { return c_str_; }
```

If you want a pointer, just swap the `&` for a `*` and return `&c_str_`.

If you want to explicitly refer to the type, use an alias:

```
using T = const char[6];
static constexpr T& c_str() { return c_str_; }
```

Or if you really hate yourself:

```
static constexpr const char (&c_str())[6] { return c_str_; }
```

Note that you cannot have a function return a raw array by value.

Comment: Minor note: This won't quite make `decltype(myclass::c_str())` "equivalent to `const char[6]`" like the post asks for - it's `const char (&)[6]`, but it's impossible to use a plain array type as a return type, and that will be close enough for most purposes.

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I’m not sure how I missed that string literals are references to arrays, not arrays all this time.

Comment: @SumDood No, string literals _are_ arrays. They have type `char const[N]`.

Comment: @Barry Actaully, `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype("test"), const char(&)[5]>);` succeeds while `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype("test"), const char[5]>);` fails.  This seems to demonstrate that the type of a string literal is a reference to array of const chars, right?

Comment: @SumDood No. String literals [are arrays](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex#string-6.sentence-2). It's just that `decltype` [adds a reference](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#decltype-1.5)

Comment: I see, I didn't know that a string literal is an lvalue!  I just assumed that it was a prvalue like all other built-in literals.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A modern alternative would be returning a `string_view`, which basically is the combination of a pointer to the string and the length. That allows the user of your function to directly access the length information. And the string could be stored in a null-terminated or non-null-terminated fashion in `my_class`.

As far as I can see `string_view` [supports a constexpr constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) too.

However this doesn't allow for the signature `const char* c_str()`. If you are bound to that, the string must be null-terminated in order to allow the caller to retrieve the length (by counting).

Comment: I agree that string_view is usually preferable to raw `const char*`, but I was mainly curious from a language perspective if this was possible.  Turns out it is: returning a reference to array, as shown in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way but a small modification is required in your code which is as follows,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class my_class {
  private:
    static constexpr const char c_str_[6] = {'V', 'a', 'a', 'n', 'i', '\0'};
  public:
    static constexpr auto c_str() ->  const char( &)[6] {
      return c_str_;
    }
};

int main(int , char *[])
{
    std::remove_reference< decltype( my_class::c_str())>::type arr = { 'S', 'a', 'a', 'v', 'i', '\0'};

    std::cout<< arr<< " is a beautiful name."<< std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output: `Saavi is a beautiful name.`

Now `my_class::c_str()` return reference `const char ( &)[6]`. This reference is very special because it can only refer an constant array of `char` type which have length `6` and it is different from pointer. Now type information can be retrieve. 
So `std::remove_reference<>::type` comes to rescue, its `type` can point to the type the reference is referring which is `const char[6]`.
To verify this, i have created `const char` array named `arr` which is `const char[6]` without specifying length of array.